# Insert thousands of rows in MySQL database table using C# in Efficient way

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to insert unknown number of rows in MySQL database. The rows are coming in List of Dictionary.
Each dictionary in List represent a row. For each row, Dictionary `key` contains **column name**, and `value` contains the **column data** for that row.

I have achieved this something like this -

```
public long InsertMultiple(string TableName, List<Dictionary<string, string>> listMultipleRows)
{
    try
    {
        string columnNames = null;
        StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
        int columnLength = listMultipleRows.First().Select(x => x.Key).ToArray().Length;

        //Fetching required column names.
        if (listMultipleRows.Count > 0)
            columnNames = string.Join(", ", listMultipleRows.First().Select(x => x.Key).ToArray());

        //Preparing command
        if (columnNames != null)
            sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " (" + columnNames + ") VALUES ");

        //Preparing column format like - '{0}','{1}'......
        string columnFormat = "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < columnLength; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                columnFormat = columnFormat + ",";
            columnFormat = columnFormat + "'{" + i + "}'";
        }
        columnFormat = columnFormat + ")";                

        //Appending each row values. Actual rows which needs to be inserted.
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in listMultipleRows)
        {
            Rows.Add(string.Format(columnFormat, row.Select(x => MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(x.Value)).ToArray()));
        }

        sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
        sCommand.Append(";");

        MySqlCommand Comm = new MySqlCommand();
        Comm.CommandText = sCommand.ToString();
        Comm.Connection = m_Conn;
        //One shot insertion operation
        return Convert.ToInt64(ExecuteScalar(Comm));  
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> The execution time for 2800 records is around 500 ms. Which is superb.
>   What I am worried here is about the SQL Injection. Generally, we use
>   parameterized query to avoid SQL injection. But in my case, the rows
>   can be in large numbers so can't create so many parameters.  Is there
>   a solution to this problem? or some better way?

Comment: I dont see the difference between looping the inputs and concatenating and binding variables. Specailly if you use PDO

Comment: And as to injection, that depends upon where you get your list! Is that user input?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Its a dictionary prepared by deserializing some JSON file. In a way, yes, its a user input.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Parameters may be more than 30k in specific cases. As I know, there is limit of 2100.

Comment: @ArpitGupta Give it a try to EF, deserialize the JSON to a class and then you can call SaveChanges and EF will handle all parametizing and saving to the db. Way better than using raw ado.net or mysql libs for c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper is very good at looping with parameters

Comment: Why build an insert string instead of prebuilt, parameterized strings? Do you expect schema changes in the tables? But as @gilliduck mentioned, I'd go with Dapper.

Comment: @gilliduck Need to check for Dapper.

Comment: @Prix Will check about EF. Apart from that, Can you have any idea of improvement in this existing scenario?

Comment: If you really want to do a batch insert of a large file, you can dump/convert the list to a temporary delimited file, and use MySqlBulkLoader.

Comment: @ArpitGupta yes, don't use it.